# Selecting duplicates with a unique identifying column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that looks like this (simplified)

```
| uniqueID | value1 | value2 | value3 |
|:--------:|:------:|:------:|:------:|
|     1    |    a   |    b   |    c   |
|     2    |    e   |    f   |    g   |
|     3    |    a   |    b   |    c   |
|     4    |    a   |    b   |    c   |
|     5    |    e   |    f   |    g   |
```

The end goal is to get a list of uniqueIDs that have the same value1, value2, and value3 but without the first occurence. For the table above I would ideally like the result of the query to be:

```
| uniqueID |
|:--------:|
|     3    |
|     4    |
|     5    |
```

This way I can then remove those uniqueID's from the table later. My current code looks like this:

```
select value1, value2, value3, count(*)
from myTable
group by value1, value2, value3 having count(*) > 1;
```

This gets me:

```
| value1 | value2 | value3 | count(*) |
|:------:|:------:|:------:|:--------:|
|    a   |    b   |    c   |     3    |
|    e   |    f   |    g   |     2    |
```

Which works great to see which set of values are duplicated but does not help me identify the uniqueID for them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
SELECT uniqueID, value1, value2, value3 FROM (
    SELECT uniqueID, value1, value2, value3
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY value1, value2, value3 ORDER BY uniqueID ) AS rn
      FROM mytable
) WHERE rn > 1;
```

This will get all the unique combinations of values for which more than one exists and will eliminate the first (by filtering on the result of `ROW_NUMBER()`) where "first" is the minimum value of `uniqueID` for that combination.

If you wanted to get the ones that *you don't want removed*, you could do the following instead:

```
SELECT uniqueID, value1, value2, value3 FROM (
    SELECT uniqueID, value1, value2, value3
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY value1, value2, value3 ORDER BY uniqueID ) AS rn
      FROM mytable
) WHERE rn = 1;
```

**EDIT: Fixed some identifier names.** Really, not a good idea to use CamelCase and headlessCamelCase in Oracle, where your table names and column names are just going to be converted to uppercase (unless you quote your identifiers).

Comment: Thank you David Faber, this answered my question perfectly. It was very helpful. Also the CamelCase is an old habit but the actual table I am using has names like UNIQUE_ID. The example I wrote out was just poorly named.